# Relative paths in ionic 6 apps

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, webpack, vite, ionic6

paths definition in tsconfig.json file.

```
"baseUrl": ".",
  "paths": {
    "@assets*": ["src/assets*"],
    "@components*": ["src/components*"],
    "@pages*": ["src/pages*"],
    "@theme*": ["src/theme*"],
    "@methods*": ["src/methods*"],
    "@interfaces*": ["src/interfaces*"],
    "@mock_data*": ["src/mock_data*"]
},
```

Error: `Can't resolve '@components/MainTabs/MainTabs'`

I think ionic 6 uses `vite`, so I don't know where to add the `config`

Answer (score 0):

The regex for the file/directory won't match nested files till you put / for separating directories.

```
  "@components/*": ["src/components/*"]
```

Imagine you want to use `@component/a/b/c.txs` then you can think of `*` as an alias for `a/b/c.ts` and then forward that alias in a different directory path (here) `src/compoments/a/b/c.ts`